# PrimeFaces ajax don't work

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Why, when I use `ajax = true` the action button primefaces does not work?
Whenever this happens to me, someone has the same situation?

```
<p:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.insert()}" value="Gravar" 
    icon="/resources/img/accept.ico">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Tem Certeza??" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>  
    </p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">  
    <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
    icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
    <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
    icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
</p:confirmDialog>
```

In this case, I need two things and none work.

Comment: Send more code.  where is our dialog code? If possible submit content of <h:form>

Comment: Look in browser's HTTP traffic monitor and JS console for clues.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes. Some Components  can prevent each other .İf like a Button does not work.You have to add process="@this". Directly your button works.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.insert()}" value="Gravar"  **process="@this"**
icon="/resources/img/accept.ico">
<p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Tem Certeza??" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>  
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">  
<p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
<p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should review "action" attribute in commandButton (**action="#{usuarioBean.insert}"**).

```
<p:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.insert}" value="Gravar" 
    icon="/resources/img/accept.ico">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Tem Certeza??" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>  
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: whats the problem with action attribute?

Comment: I think you should use action="#{usuarioBean.insert}" instead using action="#{usuarioBean.insert()}". If it does not work, You should append attribute process="@this". Ex: <p:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.insert}" process="@this" value="Gravar" />